# If bitwise OR operator is used twice between two number. How will that work?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, binary-operators, bitwise-or, logical-or

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 60; // 0011 1100
    int b = 13; // 0000 1101
    int c = 0;
    c = a || b;
    printf("%d",c);
    return 0;
}
```

The output for my code is 1. Can anyone explain how that worked?

Comment: The `||` operator is the "logical or" operator, not the "bitwise or" operator; for "bitwise or", use `|` instead.  Also, don't forget to put a newline at the end of outputs; it makes it easier to read, and will matter later if you are debugging sequences.  Without a newline, the output may not appear when you expect, misleading you about where your program crashed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this statement

```
 c = a || b; // 0011 1101
```

there is used the logical OR operator `||` that yields 1 if either of operands is unequal to 0.

From the C Standard (6.5.14 Logical OR operator)

> 3 The || operator shall yield 1 if either of its operands compare
>   unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type int.

The bitwise inclusive OR operator `|` is written like

```
 c = a | b; // 0011 1101
```

If you will write like

```
 c = a | | b;
```

with a blank between the symbols `'|'` then the compiler will issue an error. You may not use such a way any binary operator because such an operator expects operands on the left and the right sides of the operator.

Of course, if you will write for example like

```
c = a + + b;
```

then there is the first operator `+` is the binary plus and the second operator `+`  is the unary plus operator. That is there is no two consecutive binary operators `+`.

You should not mix logical operators `||` and `&&` with bitwise operators `|` and `&`.